# Registering irrlicht class into angelscript gives <unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, scripting, registering

I am attempting to register the following function from Irrlicht, dimension2df:

```
template <class U>
dimension2d<T>& operator=(const dimension2d<U>& other)
{ 
    Width = (T) other.Width;
    Height = (T) other.Height;
    return *this;
}
```

Here is the full source file: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/dimension2d_8h_source.html

Here is my C++ code to register the overloaded operator= into angelscript:

```
r = engine->RegisterObjectMethod("dimension2f", "bool opEquals(const dimension2f &in) const", asFUNCTIONPR(operator==, (dimension2df&), bool),asCALL_CDECL_OBJFIRST); assert(r >= 0);
```

Upon compiling, I get the following error message:

```
E:\pb\main.cpp|295|error: invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'bool (*)(irr::core::dimension2df&)'|
```

Looking at the documentation, it describes this method for registering an operator function:

```
struct Vector3
{
Vector3();
Vector3(const Vector3 &other);
Vector3(float x, float y, float z);

Vector3 &operator=(const Vector3 &other);
Vector3 &operator+=(const Vector3 &other);
Vector3 &operator-=(const Vector3 &other);
Vector3 &operator*=(float scalar);
Vector3 &operator/=(float scalar);

friend bool operator==(const Vector3 &a, const Vector3 &b);
friend bool operator!=(const Vector3 &a, const Vector3 &b);
friend Vector3 operator+(const Vector3 &a, const Vector3 &b);
friend Vector3 operator-(const Vector3 &a, const Vector3 &b);
friend Vector3 operator*(float s, const Vector3 &v);
friend Vector3 operator*(const Vector3 &v, float s);
friend Vector3 operator/(const Vector3 &v, float s);

float x;
float y;
float z;
};

r = engine->RegisterObjectMethod("vector3", "bool opEquals(const vector3 &in) const", asFUNCTIONPR(operator==, (const Vector3&, const Vector3&), bool), asCALL_CDECL_OBJFIRST); assert( r >= 0 );
```

I tried to follow the example as closely as possible, but this problem has really got me stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, here is the correct code:

```
r = engine->RegisterObjectMethod("dimension2f", "bool opEquals(const dimension2f &in) const", asMETHODPR(dimension2df, operator==, (const dimension2df&) const, bool),asCALL_THISCALL); assert(r >= 0);
```